# How to get Doctrine entity persistent collection data values with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8, persist

What is best way to convert Doctrine entity persistent collection to array with symfony 2 ? I want to get the values and later by using that array value, need to get the second entity values which dependent on first entity using form event listener.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this helps you:

`$arrayValues = $persistentCollection->getValues();`

Answer (score 4):

```
$yourCollection->unwrap()->toArray();
```

That should give you the content of your collection as an array()

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have a relationship between two entities, so I retrieve the values from the related table like this `$menu->getGallery()->toArray()`